# Replace phone number in HTML with curInnerHTML via Javascript

Tags: javascript

Replace phone number in HTML with curInnerHTML via JavaScript
this code is replacing just some phone numbers o the website not all

**( i prefer solution using JavaScript only )**

also is not replacing the active phone URLs on the website you can [check here](https://www.bellareed.com/services/decorative-concrete/)

this is the code

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
var curInnerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
curInnerHTML = curInnerHTML.replace("(678) 737-6367", "(678) 839-9838");
curInnerHTML = curInnerHTML.replace("(678)737-6367", "(678) 839-9838");
curInnerHTML = curInnerHTML.replace("tel:6787376367", "tel:6788399838");
document.body.innerHTML = curInnerHTML;
        </script>
```

this is  the HTML -  just need to replace URL to new phone what is  ( tel:6788399838 )

```
<a style="color: #ffffff;" href="tel:6787376367">(678) 737-6367</a>
```

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to take a phone number and insert it into an `<a>` tag and replace innerHTML with that link?

Comment: You have to use a regular expression with the `g` flag to replace all occurences of a pattern.

Comment: Why change phone numbers via client-side code?  This is usually done before it reaches the browser -- either by a developer or by a database call and a server-side template.

Comment: if the number occurs only in that tag, don't mess with innerHTML of the whole document ... `document.querySelector('a[href="tel:6787376367"]')` will retrieve that element, and you can directly SET the values you want, without using replace - if the tag occurs more than once, use `document.querySelectorAll('a[href="tel:6787376367"]').forEach(el => ....)` to make the changes

Comment: i just need to Replace the phone number  (678) 737-6367 to new one  and the url tel:6787376367 -  can you provide some code example ?  thank you

Comment: database call and a server-side template -  is not working because in the future phone will change couple times a day - is better to replace the phone number using  javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using document.querySelectorAll to target just the elements you need

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="tel:6787376367"]').forEach(el => {
    el.href="tel:6788399838";
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\(678\)\s?737-6367/, '(678) 839-9838');
});
```

Alternative for Plain text - this should be run AFTER the above

```
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(el => {
    if (el.innerHTML.includes('737-6367')) {
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\(678\)\s?737-6367/, '(678) 839-9838');
    }
});
```

(Assuming the plain text is inside a `<p>`)

Of course, if you must support Internet Explorer

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="tel:6787376367"]').forEach(function(el) {
    el.href="tel:6788399838";
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\(678\)\s?737-6367/, '(678) 839-9838');
});
```

but you will need the following polyfill for IE as well

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
        thisArg = thisArg || window;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
        }
    };
}
```

As per comment:

For non-link instances of the phone number, it would be useful to put any instance in a span, like `<span class="ourTelephone">xxxxxx</span>`

Then the above code could be

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="tel:6787376367"], .ourTelephone').forEach(el => {
    if (el.href) { // only <a> tags have href
        el.href="tel:6788399838";
    }
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\(678\)\s?737-6367/, '(678) 839-9838');
});
```

Comment: Amazing this what i need -  what i was looking for, thank you.

Comment: One more question  what abut plain text with no active link. can i apply the same function   for plain text  ( replace the  (678) 737-6367  to  (678) 839-9838 ) ?  example here  in content  https://www.bellareed.com/contact/

Comment: What would be useful is to put that text in something like `<span class="ourTelephone">` ... if you can do that, I can update the answer to show you how to add that to the code - otherwise, you'd have to then run your original code if the number will only appear once (or use .replaceAll instead of .replace in your original code)

Comment: @IvanDern - I've updated the answer assuming you CAN wrap the plain text phone in a span

Comment: So the phone in the plain text need to have div or span to do that ? i just update the code  but the phone in the plain text didn't change https://www.bellareed.com/contact/

Comment: That would be the easiest way - and that phone is not wrapped in an element - but if you run your original code AFTER my code, then it should work too

Comment: @IvanDern - hang on, go another solution

Comment: @IvanDern - check the update - I think that's far cleaner than replacing the whole `document.body.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

you should replace the whole a tag

```js
var curInnerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
curInnerHTML = curInnerHTML.replace('<a style="color: #ffffff;" href="tel:6787376367">(678) 737-6367</a>', '<a style="color: #ffffff;" href="tel:6788399838">(678) 839-9838</a>');

document.body.innerHTML = curInnerHTML;
```

```css
body{
  background:blue
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<a style="color: #ffffff;" href="tel:6787376367">(678) 737-6367</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just added the code is not working - you can see here  https://www.bellareed.com/services/decorative-concrete/

Comment: also this will not work because on each page the element have different class and id 

<a **id="link_button-151-11"** class="ct-link-button pulse-btn" href="tel:6787376367" target="_self">CALL US: (678) 737-6367</a>

Comment: I see.. But its work for the right id.. check this section 
https://ibb.co/fH2XrxX

Comment: but you have better solution already.. from Jaromanda:)

Comment: the page in the question has the href 4 times and the text 3 times ....

Comment: can use the id or class is different on all the pages inside the content